# Why does my /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf gets rolled back on reboot. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns

I have `resolvconf` installed and `resolvconf -u` correctly writes content to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and `/etc/resolv.conf` is symlink'ed to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. However, once I reboot, the content of `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` becomes empty. Interesting to note is that the timestamp of `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` gets reverted to past time.

The expected behavior is that it should use contents of `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` and also the DNS from the DHCP server and populate `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
hcho@pi-master-1:~$ sudo resolvconf -u
hcho@pi-master-1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

--Reboot--

hcho@pi-master-1:~$ ls -la /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr  1 17:23 /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

hcho@pi-master-1:~$ date
Sat Jul 18 05:47:01 UTC 2020
```

Few things about my setup:

- `network-manager` is uninstalled
- `systemd-networkd` is active
- `/run/resolvconf/enable-updates` is present
- `systemd-resolved.service` is disabled. Enabling this will populate `/etc/resolv.conf` with `127.0.0.53` and does **not** use `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` contents.
- I'm using `netplan` to connect to WIFI `wlan0` interface.

```
hcho@pi-master-1:~$ systemctl -l | grep -i network
  cloud-init-local.service                  loaded active     exited       Initial cloud-init job (pre-networking)
  networkd-dispatcher.service               loaded active     running      Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd
  networking.service                        loaded active     exited       Raise network interfaces
  systemd-networkd-wait-online.service      loaded active     exited       Wait for Network to be Configured
  systemd-networkd.service                  loaded active     running      Network Service
  systemd-timesyncd.service                 loaded active     running      Network Time Synchronization
  systemd-networkd.socket                   loaded active     running      Network Service Netlink Socket
  network-online.target                     loaded active     active       Network is Online
  network-pre.target                        loaded active     active       Network (Pre)
  network.target                            loaded active     active       Network
```

Any idea what might be the issue here? Thanks in advance.